# Accessing an NFS service running in a docker container from a computer outside the docker network

Tags: docker, networking, ip, nfs

My setup:

Comp1:

- OS=RHEL7
- ip=192.x.x.220

Comp2

- OS=RHEL7
- ip=192.x.x.38

Comp1 is running an nfs-server docker container ([erichough/nfs-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/erichough/nfs-server/#mounting-filesystems-from-a-client)) using the following command: `docker run -v /home/mc/volumes/share1:/share1 -v /home/mc/exports/exports.txt:/etc/exports:ro --privileged -p 2049:2049 --name nfs erichough/nfs-server`

The exports file I pass it consists of the following: `/share1 192.x.x.38(ro,no_root_squash,sync) /share1 192.x.x.220(ro,no_root_squash,sync)` allowing both comp1 and comp2 to theoretically have access.

The nfs-server container has the following ips when run, 172.17.0.3 for eth0 and 127.0.0.1 for lo.

So at this point, on comp1 I'm able to do the following: `mount 127.0.0.1:/share1 /localshare` and the share1 folder is correctly mounted.

On comp2, I can't see 127.0.0.1 since that's just the ip on the docker network as far as I understand. So I at least tried `mount 192.x.x.220:/share1 /localshare` but that fails because that folder doesn't exist.

Is there a way for comp2 to directly access that nfs container or am I thinking about this in the wrong way?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Export/Expose the ports from the docker container: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose Perhaps you need to setup a bridge to be able to access the nfs share from your host machine where the docker deamon is running and the "external" computer.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an easier way but I am sharing my suggestion based on my understanding of how docker sets up the network on the host it is running on. I believe the host (comp1) that runs the docker container will have two `links` other than loopback. You can verify this by running following on comp1:

`ip addr show`

On my Ubuntu 16 I see two networks:

1. 192.168.1.0/24 (for my regular home LAN)
2. 172.17.0.0/16 (for my docker network)

I believe docker already configures your host to act as a router to forward packets arriving on network 192.168.1.0/24 to 172.17.0.0/16. You could verify this by running the following on your comp1, where a value of 1 shows that your host is configured to act as a router:

`sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`

The last step would be to add a route in your comp2 so that requests sent to 172.17.0.0/16 uses 192.x.x.220 as a router.

I think then you should able to access the docker container on comp1 using the IP address of the container on that host which you mentioned is 172.17.0.3.

Again I have not tried this but this will very likely work.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Ip forwarding on comp1 was enabled. So on comp2, I added a route using: ip route add 172.17.0.3 via 192.x.x.220

Trying the mount then on comp2 using the 172.17.0.3 ip left me with the same "No such file or directory" error. I think your pathway is right, there might be some other basic nfs configuration I'm just missing. I'll keep pressing on.

Comment: I presume after adding the route on comp2 you were able to run `ping 172.17.0.3` from comp2 to verify that you are able to communicate with the container? If ping is successful then it is very likely an nfs configuration issue.